# Generating a three-digit number Java

Tags: java

I using this code to generate two digit but I want to change it and make it generate three digit.

`int lottery = (int)(Math.random() * 100);`

Thanks

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation of [`ThreadLocalRandom#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int))

Comment: Surely you realise that you only need to change `* 100` to `* 1000` to achieve this?

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 1000);`

Comment: Or `int lottery = 100 + (int)(Math.random() * 900);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to change the multiplication from 100 to 1000 :)

```
int lottery = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
```